# Requests with .php5 extension in server logs

Tags: logging, monitoring

Taking a look at access logs and I see a stream of requests from the same IP address that are making requests to files and appending `.php` and `.php5` to the URLs.

The logs look something like:

```
104.[..] - - [26/Feb/2016:21:37:53 -0500] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2014/09/gal1-630x21014ff1e.php HTTP/1.0" 404 7817 "-" "-"
104.[..] - - [26/Feb/2016:21:37:54 -0500] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2014/09/gal1-630x21016f.php5 HTTP/1.0" 301 0 "-" "-"
104.[..] - - [26/Feb/2016:21:37:54 -0500] "GET /wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/pattern-light218.php5 HTTP/1.0" 404 25166 "-" "-"
104.[..] - - [26/Feb/2016:21:37:56 -0500] "GET /wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/pattern-light3782.php. HTTP/1.0" 301 0 "-" "-"
104.[..] - - [26/Feb/2016:21:37:56 -0500] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2014/09/gal1-630x21016f.php5 HTTP/1.0" 404 7817 "-" "-"
104.[..] - - [26/Feb/2016:21:37:57 -0500] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2014/09/gal1-630x21026f.php. HTTP/1.0" 301 0 "-" "-"
```

What could be making these requests? They've been going on for some days now, at the rate of every second or two.

Comment: For anyone seeing this, it appears to be part of a scanner that was looking for vulnerabilities in a joomla install we had. Also, found just one .php5 file in a wordpress site, so it probably isn't platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

This is bots scanning for vulnerabilities, the background noise of the internet. Ensure that your Wordpress and especially it's plugins are up-to-date and keep them that way.

On a Linux system you may be able to combat this to some extent with tools like fail2ban or OSSEC.

Comment: Thanks! I assume it could be coming from a variety of scanning programs or some custom brew program that would cause this? The reason being is that we noticed that all this traffic is coming from another web server of ours, and it was likely compromised fairly recently. Looking to see if its something common to understand it better.